# ngrx/store effects nested objects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I'm learning Angular 2 and i'm trying to user ngrx/store, but i have some difficulties with some special cases.

Example I'm trying to remove a parent object. What i want to do, is to remove also child objects.

Here are my entities :

```
export class Discussion {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  posts: Post[];
}

export class Post {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  data: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  comments: Comment[];
}

export class Comment {
  id: string;
  data: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

I'm using normalizr to flatten my state so my stored discussion will look like:

```
{
  id: "1",
  name: "First dicussion",
  createdAt: "...",
  posts: ["1", "2", "3", "5"]
}
```

I have 3 reducers, One reducer for Discussions, another one for Posts and the last for Comments. All reducers handles delete Action of it own type. Here is an example of Discussion reducer:

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: discussion.Actions): State {
switch (action.type) {
    case discussion.REMOVE: {
        const idToRemove = action.payload;
        const newEntities = state.entities;
        delete newEntities[idToRemove];
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            entities: newEntities
        });
    }
}}
```

My action look like this :

```
export class RemoveAction implements Action {
readonly type = REMOVE;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param payload The id of the discussion to remove
 */
constructor(public payload: string) { }
}
```

When I delete a discussion, I want to delete posts related to the discussion and posts effect will delete 
comments related to the deleted posts.
I used effects of ngrx do do that so I used this effect :

```
@Effect()
removeDiscussion: Observable<Action> = this._actions
.ofType(dicussion.REMOVE)
.map((action: discussion.RemoveAction) => action.payload)
.mergeMap(discId => {

    // How to get posts from discussion id ???

    // Fire related Actions
    return [
        new posts.RemoveAction(postsToRemove)
    ];
});
```

My question is how to get posts to remove from an Id of discussion ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the store in an effect by using [`withLatestFrom`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md).
(`import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';`)

Inject the store in the effects-class:

```js
constructor(private _actions: Actions, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>)
```

Use it in the effect:

```js
@Effect()
removeDiscussion: Observable<Action> = this._actions
    .ofType(dicussion.REMOVE)
    .map((action: discussion.RemoveAction) => action.payload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store, (payload, state) => ({ discId: payload, state }))
    .mergeMap(({ discId, state }) => {
        // access the posts array of the discussion
        const postsToRemove = state.discussions[discId].posts;

        // Fire related Actions
        return [
            new posts.RemoveAction(postsToRemove)
        ];
    });
```

The syntax `.mergeMap(({ discId, state }) => ...` is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
If you don't like this syntax, it can be replaced with `.mergeMap((payloadAndState) => ...`. Then you would access `discId` by doing `payloadAndState.discId`

Comment: Hello mtx,
Thanks for your answer. This is what I was looking for.
I did't know the withLatestFrom so I wondered how to access the state object.
In addition the destructuring syntax is pretty cool thanks also for that.
For people who have an error when using withLatestFrom, do not forger to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';`. As I'm a beginner I forgot to add it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I added the import statement to the answer in case someone else stumbles upon this question. Thanks for the hint!